# Поддержка кириллицы в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Как в PyCharm сделать поддержку кириллицы? В качестве интерпретатора установлена Anaconda3, причём если писать в других средах, то кириллица работает, а в PyCharm почему-то нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а кодировка файла какая? `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` прописывали? [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117236/) немного написано про кодировки

Comment: @BOPOH,
писал, не помогает.
sys.getdefaultencoding() выдаёт 'utf-8'.
Как ни странно, проблемы с символами только в консоли, т.е. при запуске через Ctrl+Shift+F10 всё нормально

Comment: попробовал и то, и то, не вышло :(
чтобы поменять шрифт я создал новую схему кнопкой "Save As", перебрал популярные шрифты - без изменений

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло)
Удивительно, что я менял это на UTF-8 и раньше, но почему-то ничего не получалось

Comment: Вы наверно проверяли в старой консоли без перезапуска

Comment: @BOPOH: напишите Ваш комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы помочь будущим посетителям (в противном случае этот вопрос (без одобренных ответов) может быть удалён автоматически спустя какое-то время)

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте [это](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-output-encoding.html), но скорее всего это не поможет, и надо будет сделать [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500785/4041128). У меня проверить че-то не получилось, т.к. шрифт не меняется (эти настройки не активны, возможно из-за Community Edition).

**Обновление**

А вы все пробовали?

```
Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings -> Project Encoding -> UTF-8 (так же и для IDE Encoding)
```

После этого открываем новую консоль (или перезапускаем IDE) и у меня начало на русском писать.

---

Ответ из комментария [@BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh)

Answer (score 0):

В настройках терминала SSH нужно поставить кодировку UTF-8:

```
Settings-Tools-SSH Terminal-Default encoding = UTF-8
```

Comment: Если судить по скриншту в вопросе, то все локально, без ssh подключения.

Answer (score -1):

Все работает, если после изменения настроек первой строкой проекта прописать:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```