# Ошибка в программе на python

Tags: python, резервное-копирование

Учу python,написал пример из книги по созданию бэкапа,только вместо gnu32win использовал для архивации winRAR вот код:

```
 import os
 import time
 # files and directories to add to the list
 sourse = ['c:\\backup\\']
 print('Create ', len(sourse), ' backup')

 # backup storage directory
 target_dir = ('D:\\backup')
 print('backup storage directory')

 # archiv name format
 target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d_') + '.rar'
 print('archiv name format')

 rar = "'C:\Program_Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe u -as -dh {0} 
 {1}'".format(target, "".join(sourse))

 if os.system(rar) == 0:
     print('backup ok')
 else:
     print('backup error')
```

пользуюсь IDE PyCharm, в консоли выдает такую ошибку:

```
'Create  1  backup
backup storage directory
archiv name format
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
backup error'
```

В pycharm стоит кодировка utf-8,подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, проблема со слешами. В строке единичные слеши нужно дублировать ("эскейпить"): `C:\Program_Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe` -> `C:\\Program_Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe`. Также, Вы уверены, что у вас папка называется `Program_Files` а не `Program Files` (пробел вместо нижнего подчеркивания)?

Comment: Попробовал с двумя слешами,нижнее подчеркивание заменил на пробел,ошибка видоизменилась :  ���⠪��᪠� �訡�� � ����� 䠩��, ����� ����� ��� ��⪥ ⮬�.

Comment: Попробуйте консольную версию WinRAR

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы путь с пробелом работал, нужно обернуть его в кавычки. Можно упростить задачу, сделав путь к программе частью формата комманды архивации:

   ```
   archiver = "C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe"

   rar = "'{0}' u -as -dh {1} {2}".format(archiver, target, "".join(sourse))
   ```
2. Кириллические кодировки в консоли при разработке - тот еще гемор. Возможно, WinRAR.exe и/или os.system используют кодировки из списка cp866/win-1251/win-1252 и вам лучше выставить одну из них (или воспользоваться советами отсюда: [Поддержка кириллицы в PyCharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461068/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-pycharm) )
3. Возможно, Вам будет проще начать изучение с онлайн туториалов? (поиск в гугле по `python online tutorial`)

Comment: Смена кодировок только меняет одни иероглифы на другие. В общем как я понял проблема не с кодом,а при обращении питона к WinRAR что то происходит... В любом случае,спасибо,попробую что-то другое.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло убрать непонятные символы следующее:

Панель управления\Часы и регион\региональные стандарты потом вкладка дополнительно потом изменить язык системы и там поставить галочку Использование Юникода ребут комп и все гуд